# how to use pywinauto to select and click button on iexplorer toolbar

Tags: python, internet-explorer, windows-10, pywinauto

I am using pywinauto to automate part of my laptop setup process which includes editing the internet options in IE. The code should change the default homepage URL,add a pop-up blocker exception, change the security level for trusted sites to low and add a exception for a trusted sites.

I watched the numerous pywinauto tutorial videos displaying the ease of controlling apps like notepad and its ability to use it's menu but in my own trials of using it to control Internet Explorer I've fallen short. I've realized IE doesn't have a menu but a toolbar and being new to python & programming I can't sift my way thought the documentation to find the answer

The first step I'm trying to take is just selecting button on the toolbar and opening internet options.

```
from pywinauto import application
import time

app = application.Application()
app.start("c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe")

time.sleep(4)

ie = app.window(title_re = ".*Windows Internet Explorer.*")

app.ie.MenuSelect("Tools ->internet options")
```

Comment: That’s why we’re preparing “record-replay” feature this autumn. I’m tired to write big examples for every bunch of such programming tasks. Hope the first beta version will be out in November.

Comment: For now you can read the Getting Started Guide (by the link from readme.md). It still requires some efforts.